# Modal para excluir Registro (.net core - javascript - Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando usar modal para excluir um registro de uma tabela.
Ao clicar no botam excluir, queria que exibisse um modal pedindo a confirmação para exclusão, até ai tudo bem, consegui fazer, mas dai em diante que estou travado. Segue meu código.

código do button da pagina onde está a tabela.

```
<button href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluirmodal" onclick="Excluir(@item.idclientes)">Excluir</button>
```

código do modal que é chamado.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="excluirmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <input id="idcliente" />
                    <div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente excluir?<span id="idcliente"></span></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../home/login/0">Sim</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

E esse é minha function do javascript

```
function Excluir(idclientes) {
        document.getElementById('idcliente').value = idclientes;

    }
```

Esse é o resultado. A caixa de texto é só para teste, para ver se está recebendo ID da tabela.

[image: esse é o resultado]

Agora não estou conseguindo excluir o registro quando clico em "sim", não sei como fazer essa função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Como você não deu tanta informação como o nome da `controller` e detalhes da `view`, vou usar alguns exemplos presumindo oque pode estar usando.*

Coloque um **ID** no botão de confirmação da sua `modal`:

```
<a id="btnConfirmarModal" class="btn btn-primary" href="../home/login/0">Sim</a>
```

Supondo que você esteja usando um formulário no seu `HTML` com o nome **MeuForm**, você pode fazer isso:

```
$('#btnConfirmarModal').click(function () {
    $('#MeuForm').submit();
});
```

Se não, você pode apenas enviar o **ID** que será excluído para sua `controller`, assim:

```
$('#btnConfirmarModal').click(function () {
    var id = $('#idcliente').val();
    $.post( '@Url.Action("Excluir", "Cliente")', { idcliente: id } );
});
```

Comment: esse comando é jQuery?

Comment: @AndréLuizdaSilva sempre que ver o simbolo $ é JQuery

Comment: entendi, estou usando o visual studio programando em .net core, para usar jquery teria que instalar o nuget do jquery no meu projeto saberia me dizer?

Comment: @AndréLuizdaSilva, basta clicar com botão direito na pasta onde deseja instalar / Add / Client-Side Library

Comment: Para usar o jquery tenho que colocado entre <script> codigo jquery </script>?

Comment: Sim @AndréLuizdaSilva, pois também é código js

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/admin/categoria/deletar" method="POST" id="formDelete">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{_id}}"/>
</form>
<button style="color:#DD2C00; border:none;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
   <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</button>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnDelete').click(function () {                                
            document.getElementById('formDelete').submit();
        })
    });
```

---

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu faço da seguinte forma chamo a modal com um botão fora do form, mas dentro do form tenho um input:hidden com o id que quero deletar. E no botão confirmar da modal eu coloco um id="btnDelete" e mando submeter usando o document.getElementById('formDelete').submit();